# Getting rid of svn status file - weird xlsx file name

Tags: svn, xlsx

When I run `svn status`, I get the following:

```
!       my_folder/~$MyFile.xlsx
```

How can I get rid of this? I've tried `svn delete` and `svn remove` but it always says it doesn't exist. What kind of weird file name is this xlsx?

Comment: FYI the **`!`** from [svn status](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.status.html) means that the file is missing. So, it was svn added and svn committed, and then OS-deleted by Excel when it (Excel) was closed - and SVN doesn't know about it. Follow @Ben's answer to get it back, then svn delete it for good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like one of the backup files Microsoft Office programs make while you have the file open. Mostly, it allows recovery if the application crashes before you save; I think there may be other purposes as well. Nevertheless, normally this file gets deleted whenever you exit the application cleanly.

These files are usually "hidden" so you don't see them when browsing your filesystem, but SVN doesn't have that problem.

So probably what happened, is that somebody (not necessarily you) had that file open in Excel when they were ready to commit changes, and saw a new file, and decided that rather than examining what that file was, they would just `svn add` it manually. Or maybe they were using TortoiseSVN and clicked the little checkbox next to that new file. Regardless, this temporary backup file, which gets deleted automatically, and is never useful to anybody after the file is successfully saved, got accidentally added to your repository.

Since Excel will delete this file on a clean exit, now you have a file that got added to your repository, but which Excel deleted from your filesystem without using `svn delete`.

So now, `svn status` is telling you that you've deleted that file from your filesystem without telling SVN about it.

If you can't delete it with `svn delete --force`, then you can always delete it remotely from the server (instead of from your working copy) by giving the full server path. Or, you can do `svn update` to get the file back, and THEN `svn delete` it.